# How to concat two fields and check if the new one includes a substring in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize to contact my database. And I want to concat 2 fields first_name and last_name to full_name and check if full_name includes a substring. I try something like this, but it seems doesn't work, can you tell me how to do it

```
let getUserByText = (text) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let user = await db.User.findAll({
                where: db.User.where(
                    db.User.fn("CONCAT",
                        db.User.col("first_name"),
                        " ",
                        db.User.col("last_name")
                    ),
                    {
                        [op.iLike]: `%${text}%`,
                    },
                )
            })
            resolve(user);
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can import `WhereOptions` from `sequelize` itself:

```
let whereOptions: WhereOptions;
if (text) {
  whereOptions = {
    [Op.or]: [
      Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('first_name'), ' ', Sequelize.col('last_name')), {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${text}%`,
      }),
    ],
  };
} else {
  whereOptions = {};
}
```

Comment: I've tried it and it worked wrongly. It just responds to all users in the User table. Do you have any idea maybe the code is wrong somewhere?

Comment: It responds to all users because you are using User.findAll

Comment: ?? I think I have to use findAll because I want to get all users that satisfy the condition. So what do you think I should do to get users